# webresources.axd doesn't work when server date is fixed at 1-Jan-2014

Tags: asp.net, iis

I need to create a demo Asp.net site that must keep a fixed date due to the application/data. ie. the server date will always be set to 1 Jan 2014, and will run software and serve the pages as if that was the date.

VM is set up, snapshot to the required date, ignore host time and auto time updates, so that it can be restored repeatedly.

Only problem is IIS/Asp won't serve webresources.axd files when the date is incorrect (I get a 404).

I've managed to get everything served locally on the server (not sure how, it didn't work at first), but can't seem to from a networked machine. All the aspx pages serve correctly, and the software itself is running fine. Just those generated axd files.

Not sure if it's relative to the install date / software build date / client date, I'd just like it to ignore it!!!

The failure to serve the resource is identified by a "'WebForm_InitCallback' is undefined" error on the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this, I find it better to separate the two concepts: current system date/time and *current run date/time*.

I would allow the system date to be the real date.

I would find everyplace in the code that depends on DateTime.Now or the equivalent, and take that date from configuration or other input sources instead. That way, you can "fake" different dates just by changing configuration, or even user input.

Comment: That might not be a bad idea. Pro's are I can set several demo systems with different run dates, and restore data independently without resorting a VM checkpoint, and demo system becomes totally portable. Con's obviously having to ensure I use MyApp.Date.Now / MyApp.Date.Today in the future, and with 150 occurrences of the pair of them already, that's quite a bit of change to working code.

Comment: Have done as suggested - was pretty straight forward to change! Can now set a demo date for each dataset separately. A little bit of messing with my base controls (ie. calendars / date selectors etc., that have a "today" button, or auto format text with the word "today"), but clearly the best solution to the problem. Thanks!